# VBA to think that certain key was pressed

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if there is a way to make VBA think that certain key was pressed? To give an example, let's say that i want Excel to automatically start on a new line inside a cell ( `Alt` + `Enter` keys ) after i wrote a text of specific length.

Is it possible to make Excel think that i just pressed those keys even when i did not?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, you want that excel checks while you are editing a cell and then execute Alt + enter for example? If that's so Excel won't run anything until you finished your edition, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Application.SendKeys`. For example: 
`Application.SendKeys("%fx")`

This command will quit Excel

Comment: This can work, but if you click off the application at the wrong time, it could send the keys to the wrong application.

Answer (score 2):

If you're inserting text into a cell, you can simply include `vbCrLf`, like this:

```
Sub foo(ByVal theCell As Range)
  theCell.Value = "First line of text." & vbCrLf & "Second line of text."
End Sub
```